# Highlight blank cell, where cell in adjacent column is not empty

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Wondering if anyone can help. I have an (unfortunately private) DataFrame which my program exports to excel.

I would like to be able to highlight red any blank cells in column  1, where the cell in column 2 is not blank.

For example - if the data looked like this, I'd want to produce an excel file where 0,col1 and 2,col1 are highlighted red.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
|  | 0.5 |
| 1 | 1.0 |
|  | 2.0 |
| 3 | 3.0 |

Comment: Can you add what have you tried so far? Are you actually using openpyxl and xlsxwriter (both of those tags together doesn't seem likely).

Comment: I'm using xlsxwriter but wondered if there's a way it could be done with openpyxl too. I've tried a couple of things but am very new to coding so won't be worth much.

Comment: How is "blank" defined? Are those NaN (missing) or empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use conditional formatting in Excel to highlight the cells. Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col 1': [1, '', '', '', 5],
                   'Col 2': [1,  2, '',  4, 5]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object. 
# Note, the index column is omitted in this example.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add a format. Light red fill with dark red text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Apply a conditional format to the required cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, max_row, 0,
                             {'type':     'formula',
                              'criteria': '=AND(ISBLANK($A2), NOT(ISBLANK($B2)))',
                              'format':   format1})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This is excellent - thanks buddy!